# Advantages of PML SMD Film cap from Rubycon over other SMD film caps?

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount

SMD film caps like the [WIMA SMD PPS line](https://www.wima.de/en/our-product-range/smd-capacitors/smd-pps/) (with high capacitances of >1uF to ~10uF) are usually huge with 2220 to 6054 footprints.

Does anyone know the tradeoffs of these Acrylic Rubycon PML film caps which have high capacitances but relatively smaller footprints? There must be a negative for reducing the footprint, that I cannot find

Thanks

[PML Film Cap Overview sheet](https://www.e-sonic.com/upload/globalresourcefiles/pmlcap%20technologies_rubycon.pdf)

Comment: There might be thermal issues in certain applications  eg: coupling cap in a CUK converter but for audio applications that probably wouldn’t be an issue.

Comment: +1 for pointing these out.  The PML look to be a superior performing cap in a lot of circumstances compared to MLCC.  The only downside I see when comparing them to  the larger WIMA parts, is the lower voltage capability of the PML parts and higher cost.